# Rails send instance variable from new action added to a new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

this is my route:

```
get '/historico_cierres', to: 'cierres#historico_cierres'
```

this is my custom method in controller

```
def historicos_cierres
fecha = DateTime.now.strftime  "%Y/%m/%d"
@cierres_historicos = @negocio.cierres.where(fecha: fecha)
respond_to do |format|

    format.html { redirect_to @cierres_historicos }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cierre }

end
```

and this is my view /cierres/historico_cierres.html.erb

```
<tbody>
<% @cierres_historicos.each do |cierre| %>
  <tr>....

<% end %>
```

And this is the error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

  <tbody>
    <% @cierres_historicos.each do |cierre| %> // IN THIS LINE
  <tr>
```

How should i solve this? thanks

Comment: Can you corroborate `@negocio` has `cierres` and/or `@negocio.cierres.where(fecha: fecha)` doesn't return an empty result?

Comment: What's the type of "fecha" string or datetime ?

Comment: Your variable `@cierres_historicos` is nil. Check my anwer to your previos question, to get the `where` working.

Comment: @SebastianPalma if it is emprty result it should show an empty datatable.

Comment: @GabrielLidenor fecha is date. My database is empty but i set  negocio and search its cierres with  negocios.cierres . In console when i put negocios.cierres.count it returns 0 so its okay. 0 is different to nil

Comment: if you are staying in the same controller i would suggest `render` rather than `redirect_to`. Otherwise I guess you could use the flash object to pass this information.

Comment: @SebastianPalma in console i search negocio = Negocio.first, then negocio.cierres.count it returns 0, so it is not nil, my problem is to pass my instance variable to my custom view historico_cierres.html.erb

Comment: @engineersmnky how should be the code to render and send the instance variable cierres_historicos?

Comment: And what's the data type of `fecha`?

Comment: thanks to all of you i solved this: first my action name was worng historicos_cierres should be historico_cierres without 's', then remove redirect_to and use render '/historico_cierres' and it works perfect.

Comment: simply `render :show`

Comment: Hello @matQ, this question will be of no use to any other user, since you have been doing things the wrong way, as you eventually realized. I am glad you found a solution to your problem, but I would suggest removing this question for the reason I just mentioned above.

Comment: @RubyRacer I added a new action to my controller and then a view. How should i send an instance variable to that new view? Which is the rigth way? that was my problem. New action, new view and send an instance variable. if you show me the rigth way i will remove it, meanwhile I'll leave it like this maybe someone will find it helpful

Comment: You already have an answer to the above question, from @engineersmnky